# Js: Find possible maximum and minimum of a variable

Tags: javascript

The title might not be clear enough, but I'll try to explain it better here. I have the following code:

```
var $position, $difference;
$position   = parseInt(($e.clientX - $this.offsetWidth) / $this.offsetWidth * 100);
$difference = ($this.offsetWidth / $position) * 100;
```

This is part of a function that runs when user clicks on a div (`$this`) and `$difference` outputs different values depends on screen width, for example:
`3.341288782816229`, `5.751848808545604`, etc.

I want to find out, if possible, the largest and the smallest possible numbers that I can get from this variable.

How can I do this?

Comment: Just calculate the lower & upper bound? Put the code in a function and call it three times: with `0`, `e.clientX` and upper bound (width of element or window?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `Array#push` to push all the difference value to `Array`.Then sort with `asc` order. Finally find the lower and higher value from array

```
var $position, 
var $difference=[];
$position   = parseInt(($e.clientX - $this.offsetWidth) / $this.offsetWidth * 100);
$difference.push(($this.offsetWidth / $position) * 100) //add all value
$difference = $difference.sort(); //order asc low-hight
var lowest_num = $difference[0]; //lower one
var heighest_num =$difference[$difference.length-1] //heigher one
```

Comment: Great solution. Thank you!